# How to add loop multiple HTML5 videos using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

My requirement is i have to place N number of videos in same place and if one video ended then next video has to start like wise....

Here i have tried with four videos its not starting the second video.

Could you please help me

```
<script>
video_count =1;
videoPlayer = document.getElementById("ss");
function run(){
        video_count++;
        if (video_count == 4) video_count = 1;
        var nextVideo = "video"+video_count+".mp4";
        videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
        videoPlayer.play();
        };
</script>

<video id="homevideo" width="100%" autoplay onended="run()">
    <source id="ss" src="video1.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to remove onended-tag and add javascript event. Does it help?

```
videoPlayer.onended(function(e) {
 run();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use it help you?

```
**In Head tag:**     
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
            video_count = 1; 
            function run() { 
                video_count++; 
                var videoPlayer = document.getElementById("homevideo"); 
                if (video_count == 4) 
                    video_count = 1; 
                var nextVideo = "ModelVideo/1/video" + video_count + ".mp4"; 
                videoPlayer.src = nextVideo; 
                videoPlayer.load(); 
                videoPlayer.play();        
            }; 
        </script> 

    In Body tag: 
    <div style="width: 30%;"> 
            <video id="homevideo" width="100%" controls autoplay onended="run()"> 
            <source id="ss" src="ModelVideo/1/video1.mp4" type='video/mp4'/></video> 
        </div>
```

Comment: anyone has more better way of achieving this functionality and also a more functionality for add of any message as like live  tv on bottom of video, please share.